# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Running into the above error message when fitting the model for X and Y. Both are taken from training data and truth respectively. Verified that data does not contain NaN or Inf.

Tried to subset the data into 20*3 matrix and eyeballed the data where nothing seemed out of place. How can I fix it.

Here is the data subset I am working on:
            1       2       3

> ```
> 12235  0.0369 -0.1415 -0.4381
> 11008  0.4285  0.2449  0.7858
> 15983  0.5557  0.0466 -0.2477
> 15881  0.8825  1.3252 -0.2296
> 14037  1.6551  0.5298  0.1924
> 4860   0.7082 -0.3576  0.5771
> 13475  0.0103  0.1030  1.4402
> 7226   0.5135  1.2396  0.9988
> 2862   0.5454 -0.1530  1.5451
> 1401   0.7960  0.9605  0.8021
> 3988   0.2682  0.9393 -0.1930
> 16346 -0.2303  0.5633  0.5991
> 15293  0.9816  0.6522  0.1207
> 895    0.6816  0.6819  0.5101
> 14781  0.2243  0.0350 -0.6212
> 14791  0.1902  0.2113  0.4330
> 4869   0.5471  1.4235  0.4891
> 1770   0.5270  0.4097  0.3691
> 15483  1.0364  0.8619  0.6298
> 17033  0.9304 -0.3223  0.9128
>             1       2       3
> 9909   0.0884  0.3513  0.7508
> 4307   0.3094  0.8885  1.2935
> 14128 -0.5162  1.0465 -1.1435
> 15694  0.6993  0.3426  0.9185
> 3709  -0.6405 -0.3263  0.2199
> 16190  0.7642  0.4764  0.3143
> 15877  0.6836  0.2586  0.8664
> 3319  -0.3437 -0.1538  0.5070
> 8135   0.1876  0.9128 -0.1812
> 13035  0.7733  1.7522  0.4158
> 12168 -0.0617 -0.0897  0.3686
> 10469  1.1860  0.3772  0.4178
> 6211   0.8808  1.0333  0.5994
> 9491   0.5110  0.6489  0.6749
> 8310   0.5609  0.1232  0.7549
> 171    1.3448 -0.7569 -0.1178
> 2068   0.4097 -0.1648  0.1831
> 4393  -0.2469 -0.4033  0.2077
> 2134   0.9408  0.2473  0.2176
> 12191  0.1368  1.5374  0.7149
> ```

Comment: That empty column? ....doesn't look like a number to me (ie. NaN). ?

Comment: which empty column..its a 20*3 Matrix

Answer (score 0):

I was passing dataframe, using .values in fit() fixes the issue and also my Y_Predict is giving few NaNs. It worked after I fixed these things. Thanks!!